# How to access element via dataset attribute directly

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have following mark up:

```
<div id="Movie" data-genre="horror">The Hills Have Eyes</div>
```

I know that I can access that element´s dataset attributes using:

```
document.getElementById("Movie").dataset.genre
```

or

```
document.getElementById("Movie").getAttribute("data-genre")
```

But is there a way to get all elements with the same genre without using any other feature? I am thinking about something like that:

```
document.getElementsByDataSetKey(key)
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could try [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll)

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-genre~="horror"]');
```

will give you all elements with data genre that contains horror.

Comment: I think it will be a problem if there are more than 1 genre, in which case `~=` should be used instead of `=`.

Comment: @nhahtdh You want elements with the same genre, just replace `horror` with which ever genre you want.

Comment: I'm referring to the case where the list in `data-genre` has more than 1 item.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on using `~=` in a string? I've never seen this syntax before and I'd love to learn more.

Comment: @CalamityAdam https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors